# How to update Intl.DateTimeFormat() with new Date?

Tags: javascript

I've been having some trouble making a clock

```
let format = new Date();
let time;
let timeBtn = document.querySelector("#time");

options = {
    year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric',
    hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric',
    hour12: true,weekday : 'short'
};
time = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', options).format(format);
timeBtn.innerHTML = time;
setInterval(updateTime,1000);
console.log("updatecalled");
function updateTime(){
    time = Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', options).format(format); ///not updating

    timeBtn.innerHTML = time;
   
}
```

When i refresh the browser, the time is correct, even the seconds but when I try to update it, the time stays still and doesnt change , the code in the updateTime() function does run every second. please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've added some annotations. It seems there are a couple of main confusions:

- Variable naming. For example, `format` is a datetime, not a format. `time` is a formatted datetime string.
- Declaring variables in scopes where they're not required (neither `format` nor `time` need to be declared at the top)
- This isn't causing the bug, but don't declare variables without a `let` or `const` keyword - it pollutes the global scope and the `window` object.

```js
/* We don't need to initialize these up here */
// let format = new Date();
// let time;

/* Use `const` for variables that don't need to be reassigned */
const timeBtn = document.querySelector("#time");

/* Always use `const` or `let` to declare variables */
const options = {
    year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric',
    hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric',
    hour12: true, weekday : 'short'
};

/* We might as well initialize this up here,
   as we don't need a new instance each time the function is called
   (the `options` don't change) */
const formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', options);

/* Just call the function once - no need to repeat the same code here */
// time = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', options).format(format);
// timeBtn.innerHTML = time;

/* Call the function once when our code loads... */
updateTime();
/* ...then periodically at intervals of 1000 ms */
setInterval(updateTime, 1000);

// console.log("updatecalled");
/* `updateTime` wasn't called here in your original code, so not clear
   what this log statement was for */

function updateTime() {
    /* Don't name this variable `format` - it's a datetime, not a format */
    const dateTime = new Date();
    const formattedDateTime = formatter.format(dateTime);

    /* `formattedDateTime` is a normal string, not HTML, so we should
       set the element's `textContent`, not `innerHTML` */
    timeBtn.textContent = formattedDateTime;
}
```

```html
<button id="time"></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you need to `wrap` `format` in a function and get a `return` `dateFormat` each time you want the same `DateTimeFormat`

As soon as you load the page the first `DateTimeFormat` format the date but `setInterval` will not update the format since its already been `loaded` so you need a `function` with `return` with `new date()` `format` from it.

If you want use `new Date` once only and do not any `repetition` then you can add `let format = new Date();` inside the `dateFormat()` function and it work that as well.

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
let format = new Date();
let time;
let timeBtn = document.querySelector("#time");

let options = {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'numeric',
  day: 'numeric',
  hour: 'numeric',
  minute: 'numeric',
  second: 'numeric',
  hour12: true,
  weekday: 'short'
};

//formmatter
let dtFormatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', options)

//Set initial
time = dtFormatter.format(format);
timeBtn.innerHTML = time;

//format
function dateFormat() {
  let currDate = new Date();
  let date = dtFormatter.format(currDate);
  return date //callback
}

function updateTime() {
  time = dateFormat()
  timeBtn.innerHTML = time;
}

//setInterval
setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the value of `format` set to a specific date ONCE. You have to call `new Date()` within your `updateTime` function

```
let format = new Date();
let time;
let timeBtn = document.querySelector("#time");

options = {
    year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric',
    hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric',
    hour12: true,weekday : 'short'
};
time = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', options).format(format);
timeBtn.innerHTML = time;
setInterval(updateTime,1000);
console.log("updatecalled");
function updateTime(){
    time = Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', options).format(new Date()); /// use new Date() here

    timeBtn.innerHTML = time;
   
}
```